# LinqToDB Relationship returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have been trying to get an entity that is called AppUser with its detail. I have used 2 different methods to get User and its relationship.

I have used **a linq join query** and **an include extension method**, but the relationship that is called UserDetail returns null **for both of them.**

[image]

Here is my implementations.

```
public AppUserDetailDto GetUserDetailByUserName(string userName)
{
    //TODO: Code needs to be refactored
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userName));

    var appuser = from user in _appUserRepository.Table
                  join userdetail in _appUserDetailRepository.Table on user.DetailId equals 
                  userdetail.Id
                  where user.userName == userName
                  select user;

    var deger = _appUserRepository.Find(x => x.UserName == userName, x => x.Include(t => t.UserDetail)).FirstOrDefault();

    var user2 = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);
    _userManager.Users.Include(u => u.UserDetail);

    var detail = user2.UserDetail;

    return null;
}
```

Here is my AppUser class.

```
public class AppUser : BaseEntity, IAppUser
{
    [Required, Identity]
    [Key]
    public new int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("UserDetail")]
    public int DetailId { get; set; }

    public virtual AppUserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
}
```

The query runs properly on Sql Server side.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good with LINQ queries, so I'll talk about the extension method approach you tried.

With your current code, once you fetched the user with -

```cs
var user2 = _userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);
```

the following line will do nothing -

```cs
_userManager.Users.Include(u => u.UserDetail);
```

It will not fetch the related `UserDetail` entity from the database, because it does not execute anything. To execute it (translate it to a SQL query) you must call `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `ToList()` etc method on it.

Try it like -

```cs
var user2 = _userManager.Users
            .Include(u => u.UserDetail)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);

var detail = user2.UserDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify UserDetail in select.

```
    var appuser = from user in _appUserRepository.Table
                  join userdetail in _appUserDetailRepository.Table on user.DetailId equals 
                  userdetail.Id
                  where user.userName == userName
                  select new
                  {
                      user,
                      userdetail
                  };
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem has been solved by using LinqToDB LoadWith extension method and using Association mapping attribute for my AppUser and AppUserDetail. Include extension method can not be used for LinqToDB implementations.

Here is my AppUser class.

```
public class AppUser : BaseEntity, IAppUser
{
    [Required, Identity]
    [Key]
    public new int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("UserDetail")]
    public int DetailId { get; set; }

    [LinqToDBAssociation.Association(ThisKey = nameof(DetailId), OtherKey = nameof(AppUserDetail.Id), CanBeNull = true, Relationship = Relationship.OneToOne)]
    public virtual AppUserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
    public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }

    [LinqToDBAssociation.Association(ThisKey = "Id", OtherKey = "CreatedBy", CanBeNull = true)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Post> UserPosts { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code implementation.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an user detail by username
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public AppUserDetailDto GetUserDetailByUserName(string userName)
    {
        //TODO: Code needs to be refactored
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userName));

        var appUser = _appUserRepository.Table.LoadWith(t => t.UserDetail).FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);

        AppUserDetailDto dto = new AppUserDetailDto
        {
            Id = appUser.Id,
            UserName = appUser.UserName,
            CoverPhotoUrl = appUser.UserDetail.CoverPhotoPath,
            ProfilePhotoUrl = appUser.UserDetail.ProfilePhotoPath,
            RegisteredDate = appUser.CreatedDate,
            UserPosts = _postService.GetUserPostsWithDto(appUser.Id)
        };

        return dto;
    }
```